# Problems with clipping

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera

I've managed to get my animation to a point where it works properly, now I'm trying to render it. When I go to render, or even to the Camera View in the 3D view, the scene is clipped and none of my objects are visible! I've tried altering the camera's "Clip Start" and "Clip End" values, doing so had no effect.

My scene in the 3D view:
[image: 3dview]

The same scene, from the same perspective, in Camera view:
[image: cameraview]

How do I get it to render correctly, even from the Camera View perspective?

Edit: .blend file available at http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36540

Comment: Did you try to use a very large value for the max camera clipping?

Comment: The default value looks to be 1000 - I tried going all the way up to 100000 in multiples of 10, doing so had no effect. I'm not sure how to attach the .blend file to this question, or I'd do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clipping settings you have adjusted are those for the 3D view.

To adjust the settings for the camera;
Select the camera.
In the "Properties Window", select the "Object Data" tab (camera icon).
In the "Lens" panel you will find the camera clipping settings.

Answer (score 2):

You changed the clipping value for the 3D View, but you should change it (with camera selected) in:

[image]