# Everything is hidden except one object

Tags: 3d-view

I'm working on some animation shots and suddenly everything was gone. Except one object.

I have tried to open the scene on other computers, reboot, unhide all,...

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: ...and have you tried to unhide all other objects? *there are* other objects, but hidden right?

Comment: ... outliner in screenshot would clear that up..  [clipping maybe](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32398/problems-with-clipping)?

Comment: Try to press Alt H to display all objects (in the case they are just hidden). Otherwise, upload your .blend via http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and attach it to your post.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The objects are not hidden (tried to unhide all) and this is not a clipping issue. I have probably deleted them or did something stupid. I'm not sure I can share the .blend because of the NDA I signed :/

However I did find a **solution to preserve my work**: I have opened an earlier version of the shot (which was working fine) and imported the actions from the bad version.

Thanks again and if I find how I did this mess, I will update this post.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution to the problem (which might be me doing stupid things on my file) but a solution to preserve my work:

I have opened an earlier version of the shot (which was working fine) and imported the actions from the bad version.

Thank you for your help everyone!